# get all the classes with main method in Eclipse Java project

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I'm working on an Eclipse plugin to help people manage their project.

Is there a way to list all the classes with the `main` method under a project by Java code?

Comment: You would use the [Eclipse JDT Abstract Syntax Tree](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseJDT/article.html) to do this search.

Comment: @greg-449 thanks, that's what I need.

Answer (score -1):

```
I think the best practise is to use only keyboard.
```

1. Create new java class with Ctrl+n
2. on dialog box, enter its (class) name
3. use (left)Alt+v to easily tick checkbox for - public static void main(String[] args)
4. then press [enter] Finish and voila class is ready

Comment: The question is asking how to list existing classes with a `main` method, **not** how to create a new one.